# Repeating an action without control structures

Tags: haskell

I'm dipping my toe into the Haskell pool, and I'm starting to get the hang of it. For the most part, the lack of traditional control structures doesn't bother me too much. (I'm coming from a C/C++ background.) But I'm a little confused about how you'd repeat an action. For example, if you have a turn-based game, in an imperative language, you might do something like this:

```
while (not somePlayerWon())
{
    getNextMove();
    updateGameState();
}
```

It's not clear to me how you'd do this in Haskell. You could do something recursive like:

```
playARound gameState = do
    nextMove <- getNextMove gameState
    newGameState <- updateGameState gameState nextMove
    if (not somePlayerWon newGameState)
        playARound newGameState
        else gameOver -- I realize this probably has to return something
```

But if you do that, don't you run the risk of a stack overflow? Or will the compiler take the tail-recursive definition and convert it into the equivalent of a `for` loop? If so, is this the accepted way of doing this sort of thing?

Comment: That's a very natural way to code this, yes. Stack overflows won't occur---the compiler does do what's effectively a tail call elimination.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct, if the function is tail-recursive, it will be transformed into a loop by the compiler. And this way of writing the main loop is indeed how people usually do it.

As a further reading, you may find interesting a couple of short posts on [games in functional languages by James Hague](http://prog21.dadgum.com/23.html) (he uses Erlang for illustrations, but the ideas are general), and the description of the [Component-Entity-State approach to game programming](http://www.chris-granger.com/2012/12/11/anatomy-of-a-knockout/) by Chris Granger (illustrated in Clojure).

Comment: Thanks so much! I'll check those out.

Answer (score 6):

In Haskell we try not to do use explicit recursion. Recursion is a really big hammer, and for most problems, higher order functions provide a slightly more controlled solution. You're code is perfectly fine, it's tail recursive, but it's often easier to read the combinator based approach

For loops in monads the [monad-loops](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/monad-loops/0.3.0.2/doc/html/Control-Monad-Loops.html) package is nice. You're example would be written as

```
whileM_ (getState >>= somePlayerWon) $ do
    state <- getState
    move  <- getNextMove
    putState $ getNewState state move
```

Where `getState` and `putState` behave like `get` and `put` from the `State` monad.

Or if you're avoiding a monad and just passing state manually

```
until somePlayerWon
  (\gameState -> nextGameState gameState (getNextMove gameState))
  gameState
```

or

```
flip (until somePlayerWon) gameState $ \gameState ->
     nextGameState gameState $ getNextMove gameState
```

See [Avoid Explicit Recursion](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Haskell_programming_tips#Avoid_explicit_recursion) for more on why explicit recursion should be treated with cation.

Comment: I'll look into this. I haven't quite gotten the hang of monads yet.

Comment: @user1118321 Then why are you using `do` syntax? That's just sugar for monads

Comment: @jozefg because you can be absolutely proficient in using IO with `do` syntax without having a clue what monads are, if you view the problem operationally.

Comment: As I say, I'm new at this and still reading about how it all works. I've read many examples using the `do` syntax that didn't mention monads. I'm excited about getting the bigger picture, though! I'm sure I'll figure it out eventually. :-)

Comment: @user1118321 Fair enough, I forget that I learned Haskell weirdly